# I have an AHK script to extract a folder using 7-zip. Why does it not work?

Tags: autohotkey

The AHK script below should use 7-zip to extract a folder when ctrl+ALT+Left is pressed. When you manually right-click on a folder and then type "7eee" and then press enter, the folder extracts. I'd like to mimic this without the right-click and instead use the keyboard shortcut. I tried to do this two ways:

```
;alt + ctrl
!^LButton::
blockinput on
send {LButton}{RButton}7eee{enter}
blockinput Off
return
```

I also tried:

```
;alt + ctrl
!^LButton::
temp = %clipboard%
KeyWait, LButton, D
send {LButton}
sleep,100
Send, {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}
file = %clipboard% ;get file address
clipboard = %temp% ;restore clipboard
outdir := getdir(file)
if (A_Is64bitOS = 1)
{
runwait, "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%file%" -o"%outdir%" -y,,hide
}
else
{
runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%file%" -o"%outdir%" -y,,hide
}
msgbox, 7zip has finished extracting "%file%".
return
getdir(input)
{
SplitPath, input,,parentdir,,filenoext
final = %parentdir%\%filenoext%
return final
}
```

EDIT:

I have found something that works:

```
#IfWinActive, AHK_EXE Explorer.exe
^e::
temp = %clipboard%
Send, {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}
file = %clipboard% ;get file address
clipboard = %temp% ;restore clipboard
outdir := getdir(file)
if (A_Is64bitOS = 1)
{
runwait, "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%file%" -o"%outdir%" -y,,hide
}
else
{
runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%file%" -o"%outdir%" -y,,hide
}
msgbox, 7zip has finished extracting "%file%".
return
getdir(input)
{
SplitPath, input,,parentdir,,filenoext
final = %parentdir%\%filenoext%
return final
}
#If
```

But I do not like the message box and I wish there were a progress bar or indication that it is in the process of extracting.

Comment: Off-hand, your issue could be that the hotkey triggers before Alt/Ctrl are released, resulting in a different chord (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+7). In AutoIt I tend to send a signal to release modifier keys before sending macro ones. Other issue could be that the menus do not open fast enough for 7eee to trigger, in which case you'd want to sleep between them or increase send pause.

Comment: What are the lines 7-30 for? They're unreachable code. What exactly are you asking for help for? Seems like you have two approaches in there, both of which seem very hard/impossible to understand without someone being familiar with what you're doing. I mean, what on earth is e.g `7eee` supposed to be? I can guess that it's supposed to trigger some shortcut(s), but that's all I can guess.

Comment: @0x464e Please read the description I gave in the post for `7eee`.

Comment: @YellowAfterlife I increased the sleep delay from 100 to 1000. Nothing happens still.

Comment: @0x464e Yes, I now realize there are two approaches in the script. I was copying this code from another forum in pieces. I tried everything before the `return` line and also everything after it, but still no luck.

Comment: @0x464e I've edited my post to add something that works, but I wonder if there is a way to add an indication that it is in the process of extracting or, even better, a progress bar.

Comment: 7z seems to include a switch which could be used to display the progress to stdout [`-bsp`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm). But I'm guessing parsing the output from there would be over your head, and I can't be asked writing it for you. To get back to the `7eee` approach, if that input is supposed to trigger whatever shortcuts to extract an archive, but it's not working for you, you're probably just sending the input too fast. Try slowing it down with e.g [`SetKeyDelay, 1000`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) (very high delay, just to test)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and you're probably fine with the workaround you've found, but if you're still looking for a simple script that mimics the mouse/keyboard procedure, here it is:

```
^#!z:: ;// Ctrl + Alt + Win + Z
blockinput on
Sleep, 300
SendInput, {AppsKey}
Sleep, 100
SendInput, 7
Sleep, 100
SendInput, e
Sleep, 100
SendInput, e
Sleep, 100
SendInput, e
Sleep, 100
SendInput, {Enter}
blockinput on
Return
```

I did not try your code but in general, using the context menu key (AppKey) is more reliable than mouse button clicks, and also adding some sleep time between key strokes helps. If the script doesn't work, you may need to increase the sleep time intervals, 100 ms at a time, till it works.